# Changing webgl array buffers NOT preserving uv coordinates

Tags: textures, webgl

I have been beating my head against the wall for a while on this.
I am using webgl and I have to sets of vertices.  (The x,y and z are the same but I am also including u,v for the texture.)
One set goes from 0 to 1 for the texture map and the other goes from 0 to 10 (in order to repeat the texture.

However, depending on which array buffer I setup last, that is the only UV used.

```
    //SETUP Crate Texture
var crateBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
setupIndBuffers(gl,program,crateBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(crateVerts),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

//Setup brick vertex buffer (and UV)
var brickBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
setupIndBuffers(gl,program,brickBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(brickVerts),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

This will result in the texture being repeated 10 times

However,

```
//Setup brick vertex buffer (and UV)
var brickBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
setupIndBuffers(gl,program,brickBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(brickVerts),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

//SETUP Crate Texture
var crateBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
setupIndBuffers(gl,program,crateBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(crateVerts),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

This will make both texture not repeat.  Originally I tried to put the array buffer inside the objects and I thought it was a javaScript binding problem.  However that does not seem to be the issue.

Any suggestions or advice would be welcome.

Here is my entire code:

```js
  //SHADER TEXT
  
 var vertexShaderText = 
 [
 'precision mediump float;',
 '',
 'attribute vec3 vertPosition;',
 'attribute vec2 vertTexCoord;',
 'varying vec2 fragTexCoord;',
 'uniform vec3 theta;',
 'uniform vec3 trans;',
 'uniform float thetaC;',
 'uniform vec3 camLoc;',
 'void main()',
 '{',
 'fragTexCoord = vertTexCoord;',
 'vec3 c = cos(theta);',
 'vec3 s = sin(theta);',
 '',
 'mat4 ry = mat4(c.y,0.0,-1.0*s.y,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,s.y,0.0,c.y,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);',
 'mat4 translate = mat4(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0, trans.x,trans.y,trans.z,1);',
 'vec4 tempLoc = vec4(vertPosition,1.0);',
 
 'float l = -1.0;',
 'float r = 1.0;',
 'float t = 1.0;',
 'float b = -1.0;',
 'float f = 100.0;',
 'float n = 1.0;',
 'mat4 perspective  = mat4(2.0*n/(r-l),0,0,0,  0,2.0*n/(t-b),0,0, (r+l)/(r-l),(t+b)/(t-b),-1.0*(f+n)/(f-n),-1.0,   0,0,-2.0*f*n/(f-n),0);',
 
 'float tempc = cos(thetaC);',
 'float temps = sin(thetaC);',
 'mat4 camRY = mat4(tempc,0,-1.0*temps,0, 0,1,0,0, temps,0,tempc,0, 0,0,0,1);',
 'mat4 viewM = mat4(1.0,0,0,0, 0,1.0,0,0, 0,0,1.0,0, camLoc.x,camLoc.y,camLoc.z,1.0);',
 'gl_Position =   perspective* camRY*viewM* translate * ry* tempLoc;',
 '}'
 ].join("\n");
 
 var fragmentShaderText = 
 [
 'precision mediump float;',
 'varying vec2 fragTexCoord;',
 'uniform sampler2D sampler;//samplers appear in order defined',
 'void main()',
 '{',
 'gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler,fragTexCoord);',
 '}'
 ].join('\n');
 
 function getGL()
 { 
  var c = document.getElementById("MyScreen"); 
  var gl =  c.getContext("webgl")||c.getContext("experimental-webgl");
  if(!gl)
  {
   alert("WEBGL IS NOT AVAILABLE");
  }
  gl.viewport(0,0,c.width, c.height);
  gl.clearColor(.6,.6,1.0,1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  //VERY IMPORTANT
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  
  return gl;
 }
 
 function initShaderProgram(gl)
 {
  //Setup shaders
  var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader,vertexShaderText);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,fragmentShaderText);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  if(!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
  {
   console.log("ERROR: ",gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
  }
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  if(!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
  {
   console.log("ERROR: ",gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
  }
  
  //Setup program
  var program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.LINK_STATUS))
  {
   console.error('ERROR', gl.getShaderInfoLog(program));
  }
  gl.validateProgram(program);
  if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.VALIDATE_STATUS))
  {
   console.error('ERROR', gl.getShaderInfoLog(program));
  }
  return program;
 }
 var brickTexture;
 var checkeredTexture;
 var XTexture;
 
 function setupIndBuffers(gl,program, buff)
 {
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buff);  
  positionAttributeLcoation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,'vertPosition');
  texCoordAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,'vertTexCoord');
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
  positionAttributeLcoation, //ATTRIBUTE LOCATION
  3, //NUMBER of elements per attribute
  gl.FLOAT, //TYPES OF ELEMENTS
  gl.FALSE,
  5*Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, //SIZE OF AN INDIVIDUAL VERTEX
  0 //OFFSET
  );
  
  
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
  texCoordAttributeLocation, //ATTRIBUTE LOCATION
  2, //NUMBER of elements per attribute
  gl.FLOAT, //TYPES OF ELEMENTS
  gl.FALSE,
  5*Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, //SIZE OF AN INDIVIDUAL VERTEX
  3*Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT //OFFSET
  );
  
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLcoation);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordAttributeLocation);
 }
 
 function setupVertices(gl,program)
 {
  checkeredTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, checkeredTexture);
  //Sets up our S
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,gl.REPEAT); //gl.MIRRORED_REPEAT//gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE
  //Sets up our T
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.REPEAT); //gl.MIRRORED_REPEAT//gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE                   
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
  //Actually get our texture;
  var myPic = [];
  for(i =0; i < 16; i ++)
  {
   for(j =0; j< 16; j ++)
   {
    if(i%2 == j%2)
    {
     //Push red
     myPic.push(0,255,0,255);
    }
    else
    {
     myPic.push(128,255,128,255);
    } 
   }
  }
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,16,16,0,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,new Uint8Array(myPic));
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null);
  //
  //
  //
  //Brick Texture
  //
  //
  brickTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, brickTexture);
  //Sets up our S
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.MIRRORED_REPEAT);//gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE
  //Sets up our T
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.MIRRORED_REPEAT);//gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE                                                    
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
  var myPic2 = [];
  for(i =0; i < 16; i ++)
  {
   for(j =0; j< 16; j ++)
   {
    if(i == 0 || j ==0)
    {
     //Push Black
     myPic2.push(0,0,0,255);
    }
    else
    {
     myPic2.push(255,30,30,255);
    }
    
   }
  }
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,16,16,0,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,new Uint8Array(myPic2));
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null);
  
  //
  //X TEXTURE/
  //
  XTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, XTexture);
  //Sets up our S
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.MIRRORED_REPEAT);//gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE
  //Sets up our T
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.MIRRORED_REPEAT);//gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE                                                         
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
  var myPic2 = [];
  for(i =0; i < 16; i ++)
  {
   for(j =0; j< 16; j ++)
   {
    if(i == 0 || j ==0 || i == 15 || j == 15 || i ==j || i+j == 15)
    {
     //Push red
     myPic2.push(0,0,0,255);
    }
    else
    {
     myPic2.push(137,63,69,255);
    }
    
   }
  }
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,16,16,0,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,new Uint8Array(myPic2));
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null); 
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0); 
 }
 
 //
 //Initializing the GL context
 //
 
 brickVerts = 
  [
   // X, Y, Z     U, V,            
  // Top
  -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,   0.0, 0.0,
  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,    0.0, 10,
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,     10, 10,
  1.0, 1.0, -1.0,    10, 0.0,

  // Left
  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,    10,10,
  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,   0,10,
  -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0,0,
  -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,   10,0,

  // Right
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,    10,10,
  1.0, -1.0, 1.0,   0,10,
  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0,0,
  1.0, 1.0, -1.0,   10,0,

  // Front
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,     10,10,
  1.0, -1.0, 1.0,    10,0,
  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,   0,0,
  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,    0,10,

  // Back
  1.0, 1.0, -1.0,     10,10,
  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,    10,0,
  -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,   0,0,
  -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,    0,10,

  // Bottom
  -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,   0,0,
  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,    0,10,
  1.0, -1.0, 1.0,     10,10,
  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,    10,0,
  ];

 
 crateVerts = [
   // X, Y, Z     U, V,            
  // Top
  -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,   0.0, 0.0,
  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,    0.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,     1.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, -1.0,    1.0, 0.0,

  // Left
  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,    1,1,
  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,   0,1,
  -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0,0,
  -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,   1,0,

  // Right
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,    1,1,
  1.0, -1.0, 1.0,   0,1,
  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0,0,
  1.0, 1.0, -1.0,   1,0,

  // Front
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,     1,1,
  1.0, -1.0, 1.0,    1,0,
  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,   0,0,
  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,    0,1,

  // Back
  1.0, 1.0, -1.0,     1,1,
  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,    1,0,
  -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,   0,0,
  -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,    0,1,

  // Bottom
  -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,   0,0,
  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,    0,1,
  1.0, -1.0, 1.0,     1,1,
  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,    1,0,
  ];
 
  class cube
  {
   constructor(test)
   {
    this.tranLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program,'trans');
    this.thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program,'theta');
    this.loc = [0,0,0];
    if(test)
    {
     this.verts = brickBuffer;
     this.tex = brickTexture;
    }
    else
    {
     this.verts = crateBuffer;
     this.tex = XTexture;
    }
    this.boxIndices =
    [// Top
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,
    // Left
    5, 4, 6,
    6, 4, 7,
    // Right
    8, 9, 10,
    8, 10, 11,
    // Front
    13, 12, 14,
    15, 14, 12,
    // Back
    16, 17, 18,
    16, 18, 19,
    // Bottom
    21, 20, 22,
    22, 20, 23    ];
    this.iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,this.iBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,new Uint8Array(this.boxIndices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,null);
    
   }
   render()
   {
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,this.verts);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.tex);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,this.iBuffer);
    var thetaV = [0,0,0];
    gl.uniform3fv(this.tranLoc,new Float32Array(this.loc));
    gl.uniform3fv(this.thetaLoc,new Float32Array(thetaV));
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES,this.boxIndices.length,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null); 
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,null);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,null);
   }
  
  }


  //Init GL System
 var gl = getGL();
 var program = initShaderProgram(gl);
 setupVertices(gl,program);
 gl.useProgram(program);
  

 
 //Setup brick vertex buffer (and UV)
 var brickBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 setupIndBuffers(gl,program,brickBuffer);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(brickVerts),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
 
 //SETUP Crate Texture
 var crateBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 setupIndBuffers(gl,program,crateBuffer);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(crateVerts),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
 
 //Initialize and render actual objects.
 var x = new cube(true);
 x.loc = [-5,0,-10];
 var y = new cube(false);
 y.loc = [5,0,-10];
 var loop = function()
 {
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 x.render();
 y.render();
 requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 }
 requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```html
 <img id="tex" src =  "https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/cratetex.png" alt="texture" width = "0" height = "0" />
  <CANVAS ID ="MyScreen" width="400" Height="250" alt="Your browser does not support canvas"></CANVAS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up your attributes before **EACH** draw call (or rather anytime you want to draw something different). Either that or use vertex array objects.

Each attribute has a reference to a buffer. That reference is set at the time you call `gl.vertexAttribPointer` for some attribute. So to draw with a different buffer on that attribute you need to first call `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferYouWantTheAttributeToUse)` and then call `gl.vertexAttribPointer` which set the attribute use that buffer.

[See this explanation for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214731/how-do-webgl-attributes-work)

Also [see this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  I thought I only had to call vertexAtribPointer once on initialization.